No Python at specified location when running script from PyCharm (exit code 103)
I'm run into an error while trying to run a Python script (project1.py) from PyCharm. Here's the error message:
D:\PyCharm\Project\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:\PyCharm\Project\project1.py 
No Python at '"D:\Program Files\JJ\Python\python.exe

Process finished with exit code 103

i think this is an issue with the python path, the vertual environment or something else? how can I resolve this error and successfully run my code

Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow!!! After a quick Google search, I found these two links from GitHub and PyCharm that could address your issue. Without any further information on the problem you are having, this is the best solution I can give you... Please, let me know if this helped, and feel free to reach out if you have any more info regarding your issue.

The error message says that PyCharm is trying to use a python interpreter at a path that doesn't exist. The quickest way to fix this is to check and update the Python interpreter path, Since the problem lies with the path. Then you can reconfigure the virtual environment to activate the correct virtual environment. This will most probably fix your issue
